# using same jsp page for create and edit struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2

I want to use the same jsp page for create and edit operations. Now there are two challenges in this which are inter-related:

1. In my jsp, i want some of the fields to have some default value.
   Here is the sample code for better understanding

   ```
   public class NodeAction extends ActionSupport{  
       String nodeId;
       public String createNode(){...};
       public String addNode(){...};
       public String editNode(){....};
       public String updateNode(){....};
   }
   ```

   This is the JSP content:
    `<s:textfield name="nodeId" value="127.0.0.1>`

   Now the same JSP needs to be used for all above functions.

   You cannot use the "value" attribute of the tag to set default value because while editing, the page will show the default value instead of the actual value. There are two ways of solving this :

   1. Set the default values in the action class itself. ( I don't want
      JAVA to deal with view)
   2. Use "s:if" tags in the JSP to differentiate between create and edit.
2. The second challenge when you use the same jsp is    Edit action is
   followed by update action and create action is followed by add
   action.

   So when submitting the page(there is only one submit button), the next action (update, add) needs to be determined.
   Again the solution for this is to have an action class variable and a hidden field in your JSP and use the value of this hidden field to determine what will be the next Action.

What are the best ways to deal with those problems. I don't want to use different JSPs.

Comment: Kindly show the code you have written so far, please, don't post the full code, but only code related to your problem. Make sure you have included all necessary code required to analyze your problem.

Comment: @RomanC Its not a matter of code. I need help with the design. Can these problems be solved without using two different jsp's for create and edit functions?

Comment: JSP is a parameter to the result returned by some action. You may return different results that have the same parameter. You can have many actions that return the same result. Also this parameter could be dynamic, so you have plenty of ways to design what you want.

Comment: @RomanC I understand what you are trying to say. I have already added possible solutions to the problem(class variable to determine type of action and use of if else tags in jsp). The only thing which i am asking is that, is there any better way of solving this.

Comment: In the JSP you can use expressions combined with the if tag to provide the logic. Check struts control tags.

Comment: Do all business logic in class not on JSP. You can have same method for save and update where you do some checks for entity id for example.

Comment: @AleksandrM I understood that, but still how to go about the JSP's ? Should i use two different jsp's for create and edit with the create page having the default values and Edit page without any default values.

Comment: @user2757415: You can populate with default values in action class based on some condition or you can write if/expression in JSP. As I already said do it in class.

Comment: I have a question: It's good design to mix the create/edit operations in the same jsp in struts? thx